# Solving Schrodinger time-independent equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the Schrodinger time independent equation in a potential $V(x) =-x^{2}$. The total energy of the particle is negligible and $ \frac{h^{2}}{2m} = 1 $. By substituting the values I get this differential equation $x^{2} \Psi(x)+\frac{d^{2}\Psi(x)}{dx^{2}}=0$

Now I need to know 1 partial solution to find the $\Psi(x)$ do you know what it is or is there a table for it online?

Comment: What happened to the total energy?  You have effectively set it to zero.

Comment: The mass is so small it becomes 0.

Comment: Do you mean zero energy scattering solution. Saath is ODE is called parabolic cylinder Eq or weber's Eq. This comes under tunneling through parabolic potential barrier.

Comment: I need to full solve it , do you know where I can find partial solutions?

Comment: This is a [Weber](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeberDifferentialEquations.html#:~:text=The%20solutions%20are%20parabolic%20cylinder%20functions.&text=which%20arise%20by%20separating%20variables,known%20as%20parabolic%20cylinder%20functions.) equation.